# jquery to highlight current items in nav only partially working with multilevel nav

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, highlight, selecteditem

Only the final level is highlighted so I am guessing there is something wrong with my 'current' class. I would like the main nav tab and the parent of the final nav tab to be highlighted the same as when they are hovered over.
you can see the site at 184.172.176.15/~energy

Here is the HTML:

```
<li id="energyefficiency" class="blogbutton"><a href="#" target="_self"><span>Energy Efficiency</span></a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li id="insulation" class="subitem"><a href="EnergyEfficiency-Insulation.html" target="_self"><span>Insulation</span></a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li id="understandinginsulation" class="subitem"><a href="EnergyEfficiency-Insulation-UnderstandingInsulation.html">Understanding Insulation</a></li>
                                    <li id="atticinsulation" class="subitem"><a href="EnergyEfficiency-Insulation-AtticInsulation.html">Attic Insulation</a></li>
                                    <li id="garageinsulation" class="subitem"><a href="EnergyEfficiency-Insulation-GarageInsulation.html">Garage Insulation</a></li>
                                    <li id="hotwatertank" class="subitem"><a href="EnergyEfficiency-Insulation-HotWaterTank.html">Hot Water Tank Insulation</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

The javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='content/js/jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#energyefficiency').addClass('current');
$('#insulation').addClass('current');
$('#atticinsulation').addClass('selecteditem');
});

</script>
```

The CSS:

```
ul#css3menu li.current{
color:#1a426d;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
ul#css3menu li:hover li.selecteditem a {
color: #fff;
background: #1a426d !important; 
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question while looking for a similar solution. I discovered a jQuery plugin called "Waypoints" (https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints), maybe it is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for trying but that plugin doesn't have anything to do with highlighting the current menu button